# Using regex to replace certain keyword in a dataframe value in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe to store cars related information and I am trying to replace certain key "**[Pink & Blue]**" to **"[Pink&Blue]"** to remove the *space* in between  using regex but my code fails to do so :

```
Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus'],
        'Price': [22000,np.nan,35000] ,
        'Product Summary' : ['color is [Pink & Blue] size is 14' ,'color is [Pink & Yellow] size is 10','color is [Red & Black] size is 11']
    }
df = DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['Brand', 'Price', 'Product Summary'])
df['Product Summary'] = df['Product Summary'].replace(r'\b & ',"&")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) accessor

```
df['Product Summary'] = df['Product Summary'].str.replace(' & ', '&')
```

OR In your code, use `regex=True`

```
df['Product Summary'] = df['Product Summary'].replace(r'\b & ', '&', regex=True)
```